# latex ToC chapter numbers are not shown

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm working on my BSc Thesis an the Table of Contents shows a strange behaviour. I created chapters with this command:

```
\chapter{Prototypen}
\label{chp:Prototypen}
 blah blah blah
```

And in my main document I do:

```
...
\include{tex/hinweiseArbeit}
\include{tex/einleitung}
\include{tex/planung}
%
%
\part{Konzept} \let\cleardoublepage\relax %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% KAPITEL %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{tex/01_konzept/problemstellung}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
...
```

And the generated ToC looks like this:

```
Einleitung
Projektplanung
  2.1 blabla
  2.2 blabla
Problemstellung
  3.1 blabla
```

As you see, there are no numbers for the chapters in the ToC. In the chapters text, numbers are correctly displayed.

I've searched for answers, but mostly people asking for removing chapter numbers. I want the opposite, so my question is:

Does anyone know why the chapter Number are not displayed? What can I do to get these numbers displayed?

What I want is this:

```
 1. Einleitung
 2. Projektplanung
   2.1 blabla
   2.2 blabla
 3. Problemstellung
   3.1 blabla
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a minimal working example.

Comment: I would strongly recommend answering your own question (remove the answer edit from the question) and afterward accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem solved! I used 
`\frontmatter` but never a `\mainmatter`. After adding this, it works fine.